# When to create a site scoped Content type and when to create the content type on the content type publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, administration, configuration, content-type-hub

In SharePoint we have 2 options to create content types:

1. Inside the site level, so the content type will only be available to that site.
2. Inside the Content Type publishing site. so the content type can be made available to all the sites.

Usually I create content type on the site level only, as it is simpler and ease migrating the site content if needed in the future.

So can anyone advice when we should use each approach and why?

Comment: Answer is in your question itself. If you want to use the content type in multiple sites, publish it in Content Type publishing site else create & use it at site level only.

Comment: @GaneshSanapso let me rephrase my question, why not to always create the content type on the content type publishing site, even if we are going to use it on one site collection ..

Comment: It is a best practice/recommended way to create a content type at site level if you are not going to use it in another site.

Comment: @GaneshSanap this is exactly what i am asking about ,,, what is the reason behind this recommendation ?

Comment: This is the expected behavior for content types in SharePoint online, no specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

Content types are defined for a site, and apply at that site and its subsites.

But sometimes, you want to use a particular content type on multiple sites, or across site collections,it is good candidate to publish across all site collections.

[image]